# Condition to have inflection point

Tags: calculus

In my college test, I wrote that the function $f(x)=4+\frac{2}{x}$ has no inflection points, because $f''(x)=\frac{4}{x^3}$ never equals zero.

Is this right? I was given zero for this part.

Comment: What exactly was the question? Sure enough there are no inflection points on this graph.

Comment: It was to get all the information needed to build the graph of $f(x)$. The last item was about inflection points, if they exist or not.

Comment: Inflection points can also occur when $f''$ doesn't exist (which occurs when $x = 0$). My guess is because you didn't deal with that case ($x = 0$ isn't an inflection point because it's not in the domain of $f$), you didn't get credit for the question.

Comment: That's true, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function $f(x)=4+\frac{2}{x}$ has no inflection points, because $f''(x)=\frac{4}{x^3}$ never equals zero.

The classic example that an inflection point is an insufficient condition for a zero second derivative is this:

[$x^\frac13$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/whtjtyzrmh) has an inflection point at $0$ even though its second derivative is never zero.

---

**Addendum**

Related examples:

- $|x|$ has a turning point and no zero first derivative at $0.$
- $x^3$ has a zero first derivative and no turning point at $0.$
- $x^4$ has a zero second derivative and no inflection point at $0.$

> So how can I tell that $f(x)$ has no inflection points? What are the sufficient conditions?

A sufficient condition is that its second derivative is a nonzero number everywhere. Alternatively, that its second derivative has the same sign everywhere.

Comment: So how can i tell that f(x) has no inflection points? What are the sufficient conditions?

Comment: $f''(x)$ having opposite signs on a point's left and right implies that it is an inflection point.

Comment: @ryang could you explain point 1.? How does |x| have a non-zero derivative at 0? This statement is wrong because |x| has no derivative at 0: the derivative does not exist. And for point 2., what do you mean $x^3$ has no turning point at 0? It _does_. Of course, I must inform that I am assuming “turning point” and “inflection point” to mean the same thing. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @insipidintegrator 2. A turning point is simply a point where the first derivative changes sign (the curve "turns around"); most people think of it as a min/max point, and I'm certain that it's not standard to think it as synonymous with "inflection point".  $\quad$ 1. $|x|$ has a non-zero *and* non-existent first derivative; but I now see how that phrasing is misleading, so I've changed it to "has no zero first derivative" (due to having no first derivative).