# Finding inflection points and concavity for $f(x)= \arctan(xe^{-x})$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Given the function $f(x)= \arctan(xe^{-x})$;
>
> 1. Determine the domain of $f(x)$ and study its sign;
> 2. Study asymptotes, continuity and differentiability
> 3. Study max, min and inflection points, showing any intervals in which the function $f(x)$ is convex

1. $D(f)=  \mathbb{R} $ and $xe^{-x}>0 \iff x>0$ then $I^{+}=(0, +\infty )$ and $I^{-}=(-\infty,0)$
2. There's not vertical asymptotes since $D(f)= \mathbb{R}$, we find horizontal asymptotes:

   $\lim_{x\to +\infty} xe^{-x} =0$ $\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=0$

   $\lim_{x\to -\infty} xe^{-x} = -\infty $ $\implies \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)= - \pi/2$

   Consequently, $y=0$ and $y=- \pi/2$ are HO $\implies$ there's not
   oblique asymptotes.

   $f(x)$ is continuous over all $\mathbb{R}$ since there's not VA.

   We find $f'(x)= \frac{e^{x}(1-x)}{e^{2x}+x^2}$

   Since $e^{2x}+x^2 \neq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ $f(x)$ differentible
   $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
3. We find $f'(x)=0$ and we obtain $(1,f(1))$ as critical point.

   We know that $f'(x) > 0$ if $x<1$ and as well $f'(x)<0$ if $x>1$

   In particular, $f(x)$ is growing $\forall x \in (-\infty, 1)$ and decreasing $\forall x 
      \in (1, +\infty)$ then $(1,f(1))= max$

   In order to determine the inflection points and the intervals where $f(x)$ is convex I've
   obtained:

   $f''(x)= \frac{xe^{3x}+2x^2e^x-2xe^x-2e^{3x}-x^3e^x}{(e^{2x}+x^2)^2} \neq 0 \forall x\in 
      \mathbb{R} $ $\Rightarrow$ there's not potential inflection points.

   I'm confused because how can I determine then the intervals where is convex. I did go over and
   over again in my calculations and I found no error. I'm not sure if it's proper to say
   that since $f''(x) \neq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f''(x)$ never crosses the x-
   axis, meaning it is either always positive or always negative. I'm struggling as well
   to solve the inequality to find $f''(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ any idea?

Comment: Your conclusion about $f''(x)\ne 0$ is wrong. $f''(x)$ has exactly two roots. One near $-.38$ and another one near $2.07$. So there are two inflections points.

Comment: A function can have a nonzero second derivative everywhere and the latter still change sign: [$x^\frac13$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4477359/21813).

Comment: @ryang That only happens because $x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $0$, which is not the case here.

Comment: How would you approach the solution for f''(x)=0, I'm getting crazy @jjagmath.

Comment: I've indeed solved the equation f''(x)=0 and I've obtained as potential inflection points x=0 and x=2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then you solved it wrong. $f''(0)=-2$ not $0$

Comment: @jjagmath I've expanded my comment into an answer.

Comment: Can you prove your last statement @jjagmath?

Comment: My last statement? The one where I claim that $f''(0) = -2$? It's a straightforward calculation from the expression you got for $f''(x)$.

Comment: I didn't wrote $f''(-2)=0$, I wrote $f''(0)=-2$. Read carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\forall x{\in}\mathbb{R}\; f''(x)= \dfrac{xe^{3x}+2x^2e^x-2xe^x-2e^{3x}-x^3e^x}{(e^{2x}+x^2)^2} \neq 0  $ $\Rightarrow$ there's no potential inflection point.
>
> I'm not sure if it's proper to say that since $∀x{∈}\mathbb R\; f''(x)≠0$ then $f''(x)$ is either always positive or always negative

Both deductions are invalid: the second derivative of [$\large x^{\frac13}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4477359/21813) is nonzero everywhere yet positive and negative at $-1$ and $1,$ respectively, and $0$ is an inflection point of $\large x^{\frac13}.$

> I've indeed solved the equation $f''(x)=0$ and I've obtained as potential inflection points $x=0$ and $x=2.$

Yes, $f''(x)=0$ gives only *potential* inflection points; for example, $g(x)=$ [$\large x^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4477359/21813) has no inflection point and $g''(0)=0.$

Your expression for $f''(x)$ is correct, and solving $f''(x)=0$ gives $-0.38$ and $2.07.$

Since $f''(x)$ exists everywhere, these are the *only* possible inflection points of $f.$

Finally, doing a sign test at each of these two points reveals that both are inflection points and that $f$ is convex precisely on $\mathbb R{\setminus}[-0.38,2.07].$

[Desmos check](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pw1igz6yxf).

---

**Addendum**

> This exercise has been taken of an exam and I've actually been not capable to solve $f''(x)=0$ properly.

This requires a numerical method. My [Casio fx-991ES](https://georgegarside.com/blog/casio-calculator-tutorials/equation-solve/) (a basic modern calculator, which I suspect is allowed in your exam) has just—using the Newton-Raphson method—correctly returned both $−0.38$ and $2.07,$ as required (albeit taking a good minute or so).

Comment: Alright, thanks. The checking of Desmos was useful but that doesn't solve my problem. I don't know how to solve the equation f''(x)=0 and I can't obviously use Desmos as proof.

Comment: My answer is meant to address your query about the correct flow of argument, point out the implicit misconceptions, and to outline the corrected argument; the Desmos check is just a visual supplement.

Comment: You'd asserted (in an earlier comment) that you'd already solved $f''(x)=0,$ obtaining $0$ and $2$ (to the nearest integer), so that was that. It probably needs to be solved using a numerical method, since neither [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/algebra-calculator/xe%5E%7B3x%7D%2B2x%5E%7B2%7De%5E%7Bx%7D-2xe%5E%7Bx%7D-2e%5E%7B3x%7D-x%5E%7B3%7De%5E%7Bx%7D%3D0?or=input) nor [this](https://www.mathway.com/Algebra), for example, are able too solve it.

Comment: I agree that have been very useful your contribution but did not solve the totality of my inquiries ergo I'm not completely satisfied. This exercise have been taken of an exam and my principal concern is that I've been not capable to solve f''(x)=0 properly.